# Helix 3D Toolkit - object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, wpf, non-static, helix-3d-toolkit

I try to load a 3d Model using an open file dialog
so with a button click I can select an .obj file and display it :

```
Model3DGroup groupLoad  = HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter.Load("C:....");

    public static Model3DGroup Load(string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Model3DGroup model = null;
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower();
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".3ds":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.StudioReader();
                    model = r.Read(path);
                    break;
                }

            case ".lwo":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.LwoReader();
                    model = r.Read(path);

                    break;
                }

            case ".obj":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ObjReader();
                    model = r.Read(path);
                    break;
                }

            case ".objz":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ObjReader();
                    model = r.ReadZ(path);
                    break;
                }

            case ".stl":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.StLReader();
                    model = r.Read(path);
                    break;
                }

            case ".off":
                {
                    var r = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.OffReader();
                    model = r.Read(path);
                    break;
                }

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("File format not supported.");
        }

        return model;
    }
```

To solve this issue:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'ModelImporter.Load(string,Dispatcher,bool)'

I have added this:

```
var importer = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter();
var groupLoad = importer.Load("C:....");
```

Anyone ideas, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Try newing up an instance of `ModelImporter`, and then call Load on that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call the `Load` method of `ModelImporter`. `ModelImporter` is a `class` and if you try to call a method of a `class`, then you are attempting to run a `static` method, that is, a method that is class-level. However, `Load` is instance level.

Let me give you an example:

If you have a `Bird` `class`, that represents all `Bird` objects and you call `Bird.migrate()` that is a method executed by all `Bird` objects. However, if you instantiate `Bird`, you may call `fly`. In our example `migrate` is a method the `Bird` objects do together, while `fly` is an individual action. A `Bird` object can `fly`, but since `fly` is an instance-level action, it cannot be executed by all the birds.

To remedy this problem, since `Load` is an instance-level method, you will have to instantiate the `class`:

```
ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();  
device = import.Load(model);
```

Here you create an individual `ModelImporter` instance and thus, `Load` will be accessible through it. If a method is `static`, then it is `class`-level, otherwise it is instance-level.

Comment: I have changed it to this : var importer = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter();
           var groupLoad = importer.Load(@"C...bj");                                                    but my problem is now , I don´t know how to display it. Do you know how the reference would look like in XAML ?

Comment: @KingLiroy I have seen that from your edit, but what is the error you see now?

Comment: There is no error anymore ,when I only use the 2 lines of code

Comment: @KingLiroy then your problem has been solved by instantiation and you have run into the next problem. You will need to check whether the path is correct, whether you have everything you need there, whether the user running the application has the necessary rights and so on. As a result, this answer successfully helped you resolve the problem your question was about.

Comment: @KingLiroy you are welcome. If you stumble into another problem with your current situation, make sure you search on google, try to solve it and if it seems to be too complicated, then ask a question on stack overflow. Unfortunately I have no experience with Helix, so with further problems someone else might be able to help you.